# How do I sort 2 columns in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell

I have data like this:

```
Jul29  16:52
Jul30  19:06
Jul31  17:04
Aug1  17:22
Aug2  18:53
Aug3  21:44
Aug4  22:56
Aug6  17:01
Aug8  02:19
Aug8  16:49
Aug9  16:37
Aug10  21:09
Aug12  05:24
Aug12  17:09
Aug14  16:39
Aug16  16:41
Aug4  22:56
Aug6  17:01
Aug8  02:19
Aug8  16:49
Aug9  16:37
Aug10  21:09
Aug12  05:24
Aug12  17:09
Aug14  16:39
Aug16  16:41
Aug4  22:56
Aug6  17:01
Aug8  02:19
Aug8  16:49
Aug9  16:37
Aug10  21:09
Aug16  20:24
Aug16  19:09
Aug16  18:39
Aug16  16:41
```

I want to take out the duplicates, sort by the first column, then maintain that order and sort by the second column. Like the following:

```
Jul01 11:00
Aug01 12:00
Aug02 12:40
Aug03 10:00
Aug03 11:00
Aug03 13:00
```

I have this code: 
    cat filename | awk '!a[$0]++'
This only sorts the first column and something random happens to the second column. Any ideas?

When I tried `cat ming | sort -k1M -k1d -k2V`, I get this:

```
Jul29  16:52
Jul30  19:06
Jul31  17:04
Aug10  21:09
Aug10  21:09
Aug10  21:09
Aug1  17:22
Aug12  05:24
Aug12  05:24
Aug12  17:09
Aug12  17:09
Aug14  16:39
Aug14  16:39
Aug16  16:41
Aug16  16:41
Aug16  16:41
Aug16  18:39
Aug16  19:09
Aug16  20:24
Aug2  18:53
Aug3  21:44
Aug4  22:56
Aug4  22:56
Aug4  22:56
Aug6  17:01
Aug6  17:01
Aug6  17:01
Aug8  02:19
Aug8  02:19
Aug8  02:19
Aug8  16:49
Aug8  16:49
Aug8  16:49
Aug9  16:37
Aug9  16:37
Aug9  16:37
```

Comment: Your `cat filename | awk '!a[$0]++' ` would not do any sorting, it would only remove duplicates

Comment: cat filename | awk '!a[$0]++' works, it sorts and takes out duplicates

Comment: i don't really know awk, but that doesn't seem to be doing anything but removing duplicates for me either with your example.

Comment: `sort -u -k1.1,1.3M -k1.4n -k2V filename` works good with the current example

Comment: @Sam Thank you! Your solution is perfect. If you have time, can you explain it too?

Comment: i summarized it in an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sort -u -k1.1,1.3M -k1.4n -k2V filename`

## -u

delete duplicate lines

## -k1.1,1.3M

sort each line from word 1, character 1 to word 1, character 3 in month mode

## -k1.4n

sort each line from word 1, character 4 until end of word 1 by numeric value

## -k2V

sort second word in "version number" mode, which works well for the timestamp

Comment: So code worked great for a long time until January. Because it's sorting on month, Jan entries are being placed before Dec entries. Any fix for this? This error would only occur when Jan and Dec days mix.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following:

```
sort -k1M -k1.4n -k2V abcss | uniq
```

explanation:

`k1M` : does a month sort on the 1st column

`k1.4n` : does an numeric sort to get the columns in order

`k2V` : does a version sort on the second column to get timestamp right

The output will be:

```
Jul29  16:52
Jul30  19:06
Jul31  17:04
Aug1  17:22
Aug2  18:53
Aug3  21:44
Aug4  22:56
Aug6  17:01
Aug8  02:19
Aug8  16:49
Aug9  16:37
Aug10  21:09
Aug12  05:24
Aug12  17:09
Aug14  16:39
Aug16  16:41
Aug16  18:39
Aug16  19:09
Aug16  20:24
```

Comment: Try using my extended data set. Your logic still messes up the first column.

Comment: @HuaCha made edits, the desired output is also shared